# Preserving the relationship between variables

Tags: random, correlation, distribution, normal-distribution, resampling

I have a sample of 10 genes and their expression values. There exists either linear or nonlinear relationship between the expression values of these 10 genes. I would like to generate 100 new samples which preserves the underlying relationship between the genes. What would be a good way to do so?

I have edited and posted this question above for clarity: Resampling preserving the relationship between variables

Thanks

Priya

Comment: You have already asked this question and it was closed, because it needs more details or clarity.  For example, what programming language are you using, and what have you tried already to solve the problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Resampling preserving the relationship between variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62729496/resampling-preserving-the-relationship-between-variables)

Comment: @Peter O. I don't have concrete ideas to do resampling preserving the relationship. I want suggestions. I have heard of COPULA function, it is used to analyze the joint distribution between variables. Is there any similar method to do so? Thanks

Comment: @ Severin Pappadeux. Yes I posted the question. I was asked to post a new question, so I have posted the question here again

Comment: In this case, a "new question" doesn't mean you should post the _same question_ (or even a very slightly modified version of it); rather, you should add details to the question to better explain what you want.  However, there is at least one other issue with your question: the question involves statistics more than it involves programming.  Try asking your question on Cross Validated (stats.stackexchange.com) rather than on this site.